# How to check programatically if all the Views fit inside the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a layout which is something like this:

```
LinearLayout (linearLayout)
'--TextView (textView1)
'--ImageView (imageView)
'--TextView (textView2)
```

textView1 changes its text sometimes and it can be long, so it leaves part of textView2 out of the screen. I want to prevent that, so I want to remove imageView from the layout whenever this happens. imageView may or may not be visible at the time when this is computed (maybe it was removed before when textView1 was edited previously).

This is what I have coded:

```
void changeText(String veryLongString){

    textView1.setText(veryLongString);

    int [] loc =  new int [2];
    textView2.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
    int bottom = textView2.getMeasuredHeight() + loc[1];

    if (imageView.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        bottom += imageView.getHeight();

    if (bottom > linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight()){
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

But for some reason this doesn't work as expected, because it seems as if changes in the position and height of the Views don't take place immediately. When I call getMeasuredHeight() and getLocationOnScreen() I get the values BEFORE the changes I have just made. The result that I get is that if I set a very large text imageView is not removed, but if I then set a short text, it is removed.
If there any other way to face this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I think that this is not the right approach (you can do all kinds of stuff in your XML so you don't have to meddle with Java code), here is a quick example of what you can do from Java (for example, in your `onStart()` method)

```
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    int groupHeight = group.getHeight();
    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
        groupHeight -= group.getChildAt(i).getHeight();
        if (groupHeight < 0) {
            // they don't fit in the layout
            myImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I respect this, give the answer and a better suggestion. I second the fact that XML restructuring could solve the problem far better than semi-complex view measuring.

Comment: What do you think would be the right approach? I am open to make changes in my XML. Just consider I am changing the texts inside the TextViews programatically.

Comment: @iguarna a RelativeLayout with things like `layout_above` and `layout_alignParentBottom` should be a good start. I can say it took me a surprisingly long time to get good at manipulating XML files, but everyone learns things at different rates :P

Comment: I'm curious - what kind of a button do you _not need_ when the text is too long? You might want to consider moving it to the action bar (Toolbar) - to the overflow menu.

Comment: It is an image. Nothing more than a decoration.

Comment: If you do have such a long text, then you might want to put it in a scrolling container. That would work by putting the whole (root) layout inside a ScrollView and then you wouldn't need to worry about any of the View heights. Is that an option?

Comment: I don't want to do that. I want to have the whole text in the screen and remove the image if its necessary. How would I be able to do that with the XML? I looked in the documentation but I didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: What do you want to do when your text is even longer than the image and flows off-screen anyway?